# Math Domain Error math vs. cmath different behavior

Tags: python, math

I have the following line of code in my program:

```
theta=(180/math.pi)*0.5*math.asin((9.8*dist)/(vel**2))
```

when I use the above code after `import math` it gives me the following math domain error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "traj.py", line 36, in <module>
processCase(caseNumber,V,D) 
File "traj.py", line 20, in processCase
theta=(180/math.pi)*0.5*math.asin((9.8*dist)/(vel**2))
ValueError: math domain error
```

the input was:

```
vel= 119 dist= 1445
```

What is causing this error. When I use import cmath, the error disappears but I get a complex number as output. Why is that?

Comment: No I checked that too. The input to arcsin is 1.0 and that is valid. asin(1.0)=1.57

Comment: The value is not exactly 1.0 due to floating point inaccuracy.  When I do it I see the value as 1.0000000000000002.

Comment: aha, I see. thanks. will limit precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to floating point errors rounding `(9.8*dist)/(vel**2)` to values above 1.0, the asin function gives a domain error.

You can workaround it by limiting the number in the `math.asin` call to a maximum of 1.0, regardless of rounding. You could use `Decimal`arithmetic to do it in the a proper "mathematic" way, but with a huge impact in performance and complexity.

My advice is to simply put a call to `min` in the `asin` call:

```
theta=(180/math.pi)*0.5*math.asin(min(1.0, ((9.8*dist)/(vel**2)) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the error `math.asin()` it gives math domain error. it takes as math.asin(1.0000000000000002)